# PostgreSQL database was dropped many times suddenly

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

on my server ( ubuntu by nginx , docker and Django by gunicorn)

the site is run good but the database sometimes dropped suddenly and i lost my data
this thing many repeated

when i back to
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log

```
"2023-10-28 12:12:17.689 UTC [3752923] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 102: "host all             all             0.0.0.0/0              >
2023-10-28 12:12:21.050 UTC [3753069] postgres@template0 FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
2023-10-28 12:12:43.319 UTC [3706001] postgres@aeraeg_db FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-10-28 12:12:44.912 UTC [3753497] postgres@postgres ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2023-10-28 12:12:44.912 UTC [3753497] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;
2023-10-28 12:12:45.541 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/memory"
2023-10-28 12:12:45.541 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/prememory"
2023-10-28 12:12:46.226 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/memory"
2023-10-28 12:12:46.226 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/prememory"
2023-10-28 12:12:48.206 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/memory"
2023-10-28 12:12:48.206 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/prememory"
2023-10-28 12:12:48.556 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/memory"
2023-10-28 12:12:48.556 UTC [3244077] LOG:  could not parse file name "pg_logical/snapshots/prememory"
2023-10-28 12:14:11.702 UTC [3755239] postgres@aeraeg_db FATAL:  database "aeraeg_db" does not exist"
```

how i can protect my database from dropped down

Comment: Unless you are doing this, you have been hacked. Disconnect the server from the network and restore from a known good backup. Then verify your security measures before exposing the server to the world.

Comment: thanks @Adrian Klaver , i thought about this , i think he won't appear the access log , because i allowed the access remoulty to the database by default password , i think he catch the database remotly but how he can check the database name to can connect it?

Comment: Postgres starts with 3 default databases in a cluster, template0, template1 and postgres. Two of those show up in the log, template0 and postgres. As the error message says template0 does not allow connections by default, so it looks like they moved on to the postgres database and tried to DROP it but you can't drop a database you are connected to. In any case once you are connected to a database in a cluster you can see the names of the other databases in the cluster. Using `psql` all it takes is `\l`. FYI, I would enable logging of connections/disconnections.

Comment: You found solutions for your issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this happen because i changed the listen to `listen"*"`
i had been re installed PostgreSQL
but don't' make any changing in configuration files

and stopping use remotely connect to database , only in localhost

this is more save and more stability

Answer (score 0):

Take [backups](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html), [harden your security](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/how-to-secure-postgresql-security-hardening-best-practices-checklist-tips-encryption-authentication-vulnerabilities) and [keep it up to date](https://www.postgresql.org/support/security/).